# How can I pair up keys in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have 2 separate arrays, one is just the ids, the other is the percentage Ids:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 7
}
```

Percent array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 28
    [1] => 39
    [2] => 17
    [3] => 28
    [4] => 23
```

So it would end up like:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array

            (
                 [id] => 3
                 [percent] => 28
             )
```

and so on for each of the pairs?

Answer (score 1):

simply loop through the elements of the array (0..4) and add items to your new array.

(I'm not including sample code, because this sounds like a homework assignment!)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any builtin way to do that, so you'll have to utilize a loop such as..

```
$pairs = array();
for($i = 0, $len = count($ids); $i < $len; $i++) {
    $pair = array(
        'id' => $ids[$i],
        'percent' => $percents[$i]
    );

    $pairs[] = $pair;
}
```

Comment: why no just 'for($i = 0; $i < count($ids); $i++)'?

Comment: It's so that you won't run count() on every iteration, possibly saving some time. I don't think it affects things much with smaller arrays, but I've grown kind of used to writing for loops like that

Comment: wow. thanks! just did some benchmarking and there is some significant difference with larger arrays. :D

Comment: -edit- it's not like I have been using count() with big arrays, but your notation just seems like good practice. :-)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't do that in a trivial way, however you can do something like:

```
array_combine($ids, $percentages);
```

Answer (score 0):

A good idea might be to use two loops to account for the case where the arrays don't have equal member counts like this:

```
$ids = array(...);
$percent = array(...);
$combined = array();
foreach($ids as $index => $id) {
    $combined[$index]['id'] = $id;
}
foreach($percent as $index => $percentage) {
    $combined[$index]['percent'] = $percentage;
}
```

Comment: why loop twice when the indexes are the same?

Comment: @phphil - As stated above, in case the arrays don't have equal counts.